# Firefox ignoring min-height in CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox, height, document-body

For some reason, min-height is not working on Firefox. I tried setting min-height on the body, but Firefox totally ignored it. Since my page is dynamic, I cannot just set the height to 100%. What should I do?

```css
body {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

This is the body.

</body>
```

Comment: `height` in percentages works on absolutely positioned elements. If you need it to provide in percentages then add `position:absolute;` to the `body` style

Comment: @SaqibAmin min-height works perfectly fine in google chrome.

Comment: I just re-confirmed the style on an empty document, you have to add `position:absolute;` in order to get it working the way you want it to

Comment: @SaqibAmin `height` does not require `position: absolute;` in order to work. Where did you read that?

Comment: 100% of what? Are you sure? Is there any other pertinent context that we're missing here?

Comment: @TylerH I interpreted it from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height
This is the line that I am talking about: this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto

Comment: @SaqibAmin That's *only if* the containing block doesn't have a height set. I added the absolute method to my answer with a bit more info about what you meant

Comment: Thanks @TylerH it's now clear in my mind

Answer (score 3):

[`height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) percentages are inherited (that includes [`min-height` and `max-height`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights), too). From the CSS spec:

> Specifies a percentage for determining the used value. **The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block**.

What most people don't realize is that `body` is just an element like any other, and so is `html`. What people also don't realize is that these elements don't have an inherent height set. The parent of `html` is the viewport, and it *does* have an inherent height of 100%. The viewport is--more or less--the browser window, minus any menu or title bars.

Since `height` percentages inherit from their parent, and you don't have a `height` set for your `html` element, your CSS of `min-height: 100%;` doesn't have a value to take 100% *of*. So your body is taking `min-height: 100%` of 0, basically.

To fix this, simply tell your `html` element to be 100% the height of the viewport:

```css
html {
    height: 100%; /* this is the important bit */
}

body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 1px; /* I added this to make the border around the body a little easier to see. Normally you want to set it to 0 or leave it alone completely */
}
```

```html
<body>
This is the body.
</body>
```

However, if you don't want to set your entire document to be as tall as the viewport (I strongly recommend that you do), you can also use `position: absolute;` on your `body` element so that the percentage height will always resolve, regardless of the height of its parent element. This is what Saqib was trying to get at in the comments above. From the CSS Spec on min-height and height, respectively:

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as '0' (for 'min-height') or 'none' (for 'max-height').

-

> Note that the height of the containing block of an absolutely positioned element is independent of the size of the element itself, and thus a percentage height on such an element can always be resolved.

```css
body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 1px; /* I added this to make the border around the body a little easier to see. Normally you want to set it to 0 or leave it alone completely */
}
```

```html
<body>
This is the body.
</body>
```

(I don't know what code of yours is working in Chrome, but the code in your question has the same behavior in Chrome as it does in Firefox.)